# How to implement an non-rectangle scroll content on iPhone's scrollview?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview

Typically, the scrollView's content view is a rectangle. But I would like to implement that is not a rectangle.... For example....
[image]

The yellow, Grid 6 is the current position...Here is the example flow:

1. User swipe to left. (cannot scroll to left) Current: 6.
2. User swipe to right. (scroll to right) Current: 7.
3. User swipe to down. (scroll to down) Current: 8.
4. User swipe to down. (cannot scroll to down) Current: 8.

As you can see, the Content view of the scrollView is not rectangle. Any ideas on how to implement it? Thanks.

Comment: Are you using the scroll view in paged mode? Or in the default mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an interesting idea to implement.  I can think of a few approaches that might work.  I tried out one, and you can find my implementation in [my github repository here](https://github.com/mayoff/stackoverflow-13356560-nonrectangular-UIScrollView).  Download it and try it out for yourself.

My approach is to use a normal `UIScrollView`, and constrain its `contentOffset` in the delegate's `scrollViewDidScroll:` method (and a few other delegate methods).

#### Preliminaries

First, we're going to need a constant for the page size:

```
static const CGSize kPageSize = { 200, 300 };
```

And we're going to need a data structure to hold the current x/y position in the grid of pages:

```
typedef struct {
    int x;
    int y;
} MapPosition;
```

We need to declare that our view controller conforms to the `UIScrollViewDelegate` protocol:

```
@interface ViewController () <UIScrollViewDelegate>

@end
```

And we're going to need instance variables to hold the grid (map) of pages, the current position in that grid, and the scroll view:

```
@implementation ViewController {
    NSArray *map_;
    MapPosition mapPosition_;
    UIScrollView *scrollView_;
}
```

#### Initializing the map

My map is just an array of arrays, with a string name for each accessible page and `[NSNull null]` at inaccessible grid positions.  I'll initialize the map from my view controller's init method:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    if (self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil]) {
        [self initMap];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)initMap {
    NSNull *null = [NSNull null];
    map_ = @[
    @[ @"1", null, @"2"],
    @[ @"3", @"4", @"5" ],
    @[ null, @"6", @"7" ],
    @[ null, null, @"8" ],
    ];
    mapPosition_ = (MapPosition){ 0, 0 };
}
```

#### Setting up the view hierarchy

My view hierarchy will look like this:

- top-level view (gray background)

  - scroll view (transparent background)

    - content view (tan background)

      - page 1 view (white with a shadow)
      - page 2 view (white with a shadow)
      - page 3 view (white with a shadow)
      - etc.

Normally I'd set up some of my views in a xib, but since it's hard to show xibs in a stackoverflow answer, I'll do it all in code.  So in my `loadView` method, I first set up a “content view” that will live inside the scroll view.  The content view will contain a subviews for each page:

```
- (void)loadView {
    UIView *contentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, [map_[0] count] * kPageSize.width, map_.count * kPageSize.height)];
    contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithHue:0.1 saturation:0.1 brightness:0.9 alpha:1];
    [self addPageViewsToContentView:contentView];
```

Then I'll create my scroll view:

```
    scrollView_ = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, kPageSize.width, kPageSize.height)];
    scrollView_.delegate = self;
    scrollView_.bounces = NO;
    scrollView_.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin
                                    | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin
                                    | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin
                                    | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin);
```

I add the content view as a subview of the scroll view and set up the scroll view's content size and offset:

```
    scrollView_.contentSize = contentView.frame.size;
    [scrollView_ addSubview:contentView];
    scrollView_.contentOffset = [self contentOffsetForCurrentMapPosition];
```

Finally, I create my top-level view and give it the scroll view as a subview:

```
    UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:scrollView_.frame];
    [myView addSubview:scrollView_];
    myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.95 alpha:1];
    self.view = myView;
}
```

Here's how I compute the scroll view's content offset for the current map position, and for any map position:

```
- (CGPoint)contentOffsetForCurrentMapPosition {
    return [self contentOffsetForMapPosition:mapPosition_];
}

- (CGPoint)contentOffsetForMapPosition:(MapPosition)position {
    return CGPointMake(position.x * kPageSize.width, position.y * kPageSize.height);
}
```

To create subviews of the content view for each accessible page, I loop over the map:

```
- (void)addPageViewsToContentView:(UIView *)contentView {
    for (int y = 0, yMax = map_.count; y < yMax; ++y) {
        NSArray *mapRow = map_[y];
        for (int x = 0, xMax = mapRow.count; x < xMax; ++x) {
            id page = mapRow[x];
            if (![page isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) {
                [self addPageViewForPage:page x:x y:y toContentView:contentView];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here's how I create each page view:

```
- (void)addPageViewForPage:(NSString *)page x:(int)x y:(int)y toContentView:(UIView *)contentView {
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectInset(CGRectMake(x * kPageSize.width, y * kPageSize.height, kPageSize.width, kPageSize.height), 10, 10)];
    label.text = page;
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    label.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 2);
    label.layer.shadowRadius = 2;
    label.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3;
    label.layer.shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:label.bounds].CGPath;
    label.clipsToBounds = NO;
    [contentView addSubview:label];
}
```

#### Constraining the scroll view's `contentOffset`

As the user moves his finger around, I want to prevent the scroll view from showing an area of its content that doesn't contain a page.  Whenever the scroll view scrolls (by updating its `contentOffset`), it sends `scrollViewDidScroll:` to its delegate, so I can implement `scrollViewDidScroll:` to reset the `contentOffset` if it goes out of bounds:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    CGPoint contentOffset = scrollView_.contentOffset;
```

First, I want to constrain `contentOffset` so the user can only scroll horizontally or vertically, not diagonally:

```
    CGPoint constrainedContentOffset = [self contentOffsetByConstrainingMovementToOneDimension:contentOffset];
```

Next, I want to constrain `contentOffset` so that it only shows parts of the scroll view that contain pages:

```
    constrainedContentOffset = [self contentOffsetByConstrainingToAccessiblePoint:constrainedContentOffset];
```

If my constraints modified `contentOffset`, I need to tell the scroll view about it:

```
    if (!CGPointEqualToPoint(contentOffset, constrainedContentOffset)) {
        scrollView_.contentOffset = constrainedContentOffset;
    }
```

Finally, I update my idea of the current map position based on the (constrained) `contentOffset`:

```
    mapPosition_ = [self mapPositionForContentOffset:constrainedContentOffset];
}
```

Here's how I compute the map position for a given `contentOffset`:

```
- (MapPosition)mapPositionForContentOffset:(CGPoint)contentOffset {
    return (MapPosition){ roundf(contentOffset.x / kPageSize.width),
        roundf(contentOffset.y / kPageSize.height) };
}
```

Here's how I constrain the movement to just horizontal or vertical and prevent diagonal movement:

```
- (CGPoint)contentOffsetByConstrainingMovementToOneDimension:(CGPoint)contentOffset {
    CGPoint baseContentOffset = [self contentOffsetForCurrentMapPosition];
    CGFloat dx = contentOffset.x - baseContentOffset.x;
    CGFloat dy = contentOffset.y - baseContentOffset.y;
    if (fabsf(dx) < fabsf(dy)) {
        contentOffset.x = baseContentOffset.x;
    } else {
        contentOffset.y = baseContentOffset.y;
    }
    return contentOffset;
}
```

Here's how I constrain `contentOffset` to only go where there are pages:

```
- (CGPoint)contentOffsetByConstrainingToAccessiblePoint:(CGPoint)contentOffset {
    return [self isAccessiblePoint:contentOffset]
        ? contentOffset
        : [self contentOffsetForCurrentMapPosition];
}
```

Deciding whether a point is accessible turns out to be the tricky bit.  It's not enough to just round the point's coordinates to the nearest potential page center and see if that rounded point represents an actual page.  That would, for example, let the user drag left/scroll right from page 1, revealing the empty space between pages 1 and 2, until page 1 is half off the screen.  We need to round the point down **and** up to potential page centers, and see if both rounded points represent valid pages.  Here's how:

```
- (BOOL)isAccessiblePoint:(CGPoint)point {
    CGFloat x = point.x / kPageSize.width;
    CGFloat y = point.y / kPageSize.height;
    return [self isAccessibleMapPosition:(MapPosition){ floorf(x), floorf(y) }]
        && [self isAccessibleMapPosition:(MapPosition){ ceilf(x), ceilf(y) }];
}
```

Checking whether a map position is accessible means checking that it's in the bounds of the grid and that there's actually a page at that position:

```
- (BOOL)isAccessibleMapPosition:(MapPosition)p {
    if (p.y < 0 || p.y >= map_.count)
        return NO;
    NSArray *mapRow = map_[p.y];
    if (p.x < 0 || p.x >= mapRow.count)
        return NO;
    return ![mapRow[p.x] isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]];
}
```

#### Forcing the scroll view to rest at page boundaries

If you don't need to force the scroll view to rest at page boundaries, you can skip the rest of this.  Everything I described above will work without the rest of this.

I tried setting `pagingEnabled` on the scroll view to force it to come to rest at page boundaries, but it didn't work reliably, so I have to enforce it by implementing more delegate methods.

We'll need a couple of utility functions.  The first function just takes a `CGFloat` and returns 1 if it's positive and -1 otherwise:

```
static int sign(CGFloat value) {
    return value > 0 ? 1 : -1;
}
```

The second function takes a velocity.  It returns 0 if the absolute value of the velocity is below a threshold.  Otherwise, it returns the sign of the velocity:

```
static int directionForVelocity(CGFloat velocity) {
    static const CGFloat kVelocityThreshold = 0.1;
    return fabsf(velocity) < kVelocityThreshold ? 0 : sign(velocity);
}
```

Now I can implement one of the delegate methods that the scroll view calls when the user stops dragging.  In this method, I set the `targetContentOffset` of the scroll view to the nearest page boundary in the direction that the user was scrolling:

```
- (void)scrollViewWillEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity targetContentOffset:(inout CGPoint *)targetContentOffset {
    if (fabsf(velocity.x) > fabsf(velocity.y)) {
        *targetContentOffset = [self contentOffsetForPageInHorizontalDirection:directionForVelocity(velocity.x)];
    } else {
        *targetContentOffset = [self contentOffsetForPageInVerticalDirection:directionForVelocity(velocity.y)];
    }
}
```

Here's how I find the nearest page boundary in a horizontal direction.  It relies on the `isAccessibleMapPosition:` method, which I already defined earlier for use by `scrollViewDidScroll:`:

```
- (CGPoint)contentOffsetForPageInHorizontalDirection:(int)direction {
    MapPosition newPosition = (MapPosition){ mapPosition_.x + direction, mapPosition_.y };
    return [self isAccessibleMapPosition:newPosition] ? [self contentOffsetForMapPosition:newPosition] : [self contentOffsetForCurrentMapPosition];
}
```

And here's how I find the nearest page boundary in a vertical direction:

```
- (CGPoint)contentOffsetForPageInVerticalDirection:(int)direction {
    MapPosition newPosition = (MapPosition){ mapPosition_.x, mapPosition_.y + direction };
    return [self isAccessibleMapPosition:newPosition] ? [self contentOffsetForMapPosition:newPosition] : [self contentOffsetForCurrentMapPosition];
}
```

I discovered in testing that setting `targetContentOffset` did not reliably force the scroll view to come to rest on a page boundary.  For example, in the iOS 5 simulator, I could drag right/scroll left from page 5, stopping halfway to page 4, and even though I was setting `targetContentOffset` to page 4's boundary, the scroll view would just stop scrolling with the 4/5 boundary in the middle of the screen.

To work around this bug, we have to implement two more `UIScrollViewDelegate` methods.  This one is called when the touch ends:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate {
    if (!decelerate) {
        [scrollView_ setContentOffset:[self contentOffsetForCurrentMapPosition] animated:YES];
    }
}
```

And this one is called when the scroll view stops decelerating:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    CGPoint goodContentOffset = [self contentOffsetForCurrentMapPosition];
    if (!CGPointEqualToPoint(scrollView_.contentOffset, goodContentOffset)) {
        [scrollView_ setContentOffset:goodContentOffset animated:YES];
    }
}
```

#### The End

As I said at the beginning, you can download my test implementation from [my github repository](https://github.com/mayoff/stackoverflow-13356560-nonrectangular-UIScrollView) and try it out for yourself.

That's all, folks!

Comment: I implement one version, which highly rely on the `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating` function, it load the map every time, when the user scroll, I think your approach is better. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using the UIScrollView in paged mode (swipe to show an entire new screen).

With a bit jiggery-pokery you can achieve the effect you want.

The trick is to ensure that whatever square you're currently viewing, you have the UIScrollView configured so that only the visible central view, and the surrounding view that you could scroll too, are added to the scroll view (and at the correct offset). You also must ensure that the size of the scrollable content (and the current offset) is set correctly, to prevent scrolling in a direction that would take you to no content.

Example: suppose you're viewing square 6 currently. At that point, your scroll view would just have 4 views added to it: 4, 5, 6 and 7, in the correct relative offsets. And you set the content size of the scroll view to be equivelant to 2 x 2 squares size. This will prevent scrolling down or to the left (where there are no tiles) but will allow scrolling in the correct direction.

You'll need your delegate to detect `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:`. In that instance, you then have to set up your views, content offset, and content size as described above, for the new location.